# Não aplicar filter css no elemento filho

Tags: css3

Eu quero fazer uma janela modal, mas queria fazer algo diferente, algo fora do padrão `opacity`. Queria usar um `filter: blur();`, mas eu queria que fazer na *tag body* e iria pegar todos os elementos dentro da *tag body* ...

Tem alguma maneira que bloquear o `filter:blur();` num elemento filho?

Comment: Não tem como bloquear, mas pode simular. Ponha imagem com blur no fundo, e imagem sem blur no modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, usando o seletor de exclusão `:not()`:

```
body > *:not(#elemento_nao_afetado) {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```css
body > *:not(#modal) {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<p>texto texto</p>
<br />
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Basketball.jpeg/220px-Basketball.jpeg" />
<br />
<div id="modal" style="display: block; width: 200px; height: 100px; background: yellow; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 200px;">
   <p>modal não afetado pelo blur</p>
</div>
```

Comment: CARACA, como n pensei nisso! Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Você me tirou de um sufoco, por fazia dias q eu procurava algo semelhante ... Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: @RobertJunio Disponha amigo! Dei um +1 na sua pergunta. abs!

Answer (score 2):

Não, pois o `blur` é um filtro, logo não tem como desfazer, note que mesmo aplicando `filter: none` não irá funcionar, veja um exemplo só pra entender **o problema** (isto não é a solução, é um teste):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.main {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk9BV.jpg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
        -ms-filter: blur(5px);
            filter: blur(5px);
}

.main .content {
     filter: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
     <div class="content">xxxx</div>
</div>
```

---

### Como resolver

É possível *simular* um `background` usando `position: relative;`+`position: absolute;`

Ficaria assim:

> Note que no `.main` você pode colocar qualquer coisa, texto, imagem, etc, e no `.main-bg` ficará os elementos que deseja aplicar o filtro, como `blur` por exemplo

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.main-bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk9BV.jpg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
        -ms-filter: blur(5px);
            filter: blur(5px);
}

.main {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 101; /*posiciona acima do */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
     foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz<br>
     foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz<br>
     foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz<br>
     foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz<br>
     <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk9BV.jpg">
</div>
<div class="main-bg"></div>
```