# Opacidade somente no li e não no span

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, opacity

Eu tenho o seguinte código `HTML`:

```
<li class="item produtoDesabilitado" id="1028" style="border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255) !important; height: 346px; padding-bottom: 22px;">
    <div class="product-image-wrapper" style="max-width:180px;">
        <a title="Raio de Sol " class="product-image">
            <img id="product-collection-image-1028" src="raio-sol.jpg" alt="Raio de Sol ">
            <span style="" id="prodIndisponivel" class="prodIndisponivel">Produto Indisponível</span>
        </a>
    </div> <!-- end: product-image-wrapper -->
    <h2 class="product-name"><a title="Raio de Sol ">Raio de Sol </a></h2>
    <div class="price-box">
        <span class="regular-price" id="product-price">
        <span class="price">R$46,80</span></span>
    </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

A partir da classe `produtoDesabilitado` eu insiro um `opacity` de 0.5 na `li` da seguinte forma:

```
.item.produtoDesabilitado {
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```

Porém, o `span` com o `id="prodIndisponivel"` não pode "pegar" essa opacidade. Juntamente com isso tem outro porém, a imagem que utilizo é `.jpg` e não tem como alterar ela para `.png` para usar um `background` com opacidade para dar esse efeito.

Comment: cara de que input voce esta falando?

Comment: @JulioHenrique É span, errei na hora de digitar a pergunta e editei corrigindo o erro...

Comment: Mas qual o certo? Aplicar o css em qual/quais elementos?

Comment: Não aplique na LI pois se vc colocar opacity na LI vc não consegue mudar o Opacity de nada que está dentro dela!

Comment: Sobre a Imagem, qualquer imagem aceita opacidade independente da extensão dela. Se vc usar ela como Background de algum elemento basta colocar a opacidade no elemento em que o background foi aplicado.

Comment: @MarceloRafael realmente não...Não havia entendido a necessidade dele.

Comment: @MarceloRafael o problema é que a bolinha do li nao fica com opacidade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode aplicar a opacidade `.5` em todos os *elementos-filhos* da `div`, menos na que possui a imagem e o texto "*Produto Indisponível*". Para isso você usa a *pseudo-classe* [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

**Exemplo:**

```css
.item.produtoDesabilitado >*:not(.product-image-wrapper),
.item.produtoDesabilitado div .product-image img{
   opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<li class="item produtoDesabilitado" id="1028" style="border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255) !important; height: 346px; padding-bottom: 22px;">
    <div class="product-image-wrapper" style="max-width:180px;">
        <a title="Raio de Sol " class="product-image">
            <img height="100" id="product-collection-image-1028" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="Raio de Sol ">
            <span style="" id="prodIndisponivel" class="prodIndisponivel">Produto Indisponível</span>
        </a>
    </div> <!-- end: product-image-wrapper -->
    <h2 class="product-name"><a title="Raio de Sol ">Raio de Sol </a></h2>
    <div class="price-box">
        <span class="regular-price" id="product-price">
        <span class="price">R$46,80</span></span>
    </div>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="item" id="1028" style="border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255) !important; height: 346px; padding-bottom: 22px;">
    <div class="product-image-wrapper" style="max-width:180px;">
        <a title="Raio de Sol " class="product-image">
            <img height="100" id="product-collection-image-1028" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="Raio de Sol ">
            <span style="" id="" class="">Produto Disponível</span>
        </a>
    </div> <!-- end: product-image-wrapper -->
    <h2 class="product-name"><a title="Raio de Sol ">Raio de Sol </a></h2>
    <div class="price-box">
        <span class="regular-price" id="product-price">
        <span class="price">R$46,80</span></span>
    </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

> Já havia respondido algo semelhante **[neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260203/8063)**, só que no
>   caso era `blur` e não `opacity`.

Comment: Só estou tendo problemas em arrumar a opacidade com relação a imagem. Ou acaba colocando a opacidade em todas as imagens mesmo sem a classe `.produtoDesabilitado` ou ela acaba dando a opacidade também no `span`

Comment: È verdade. Não tinha pensado nisso. Perai que vou ver...

Comment: Dá uma olhada agora.

Comment: Agora deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda e atenção!

Answer (score 1):

Basta fazer isso

```css
.produtoDesabilitado {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5); /*Caso necessite  aplicar no background*/
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
#prodIndisponivel {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<li class="item produtoDesabilitado" id="1028" style="border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255) !important; height: 346px; padding-bottom: 22px;">
    <div class="product-image-wrapper" style="max-width:180px;">
        <a title="Raio de Sol " class="product-image">
            <img id="product-collection-image-1028" src="raio-sol.jpg" alt="Raio de Sol ">
            <span style="" id="prodIndisponivel" class="prodIndisponivel">Produto Indisponível</span>
        </a>
    </div> <!-- end: product-image-wrapper -->
    <h2 class="product-name"><a title="Raio de Sol ">Raio de Sol </a></h2>
    <div class="price-box">
        <span class="regular-price" id="product-price">
        <span class="price">R$46,80</span></span>
    </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thecodermarcelo/4hsdusdL/16/